# React Native POST "multpart form-data" 500 server error

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, post

When I try to POST an image to my Node/Express server (deployed on Heroku), then I get a 500 server error.

POSTing through Postman works just fine.

Here is my React Native code:

```
upload = async uri => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("photo", {
    uri,
    name: `photo`,
    type: `image/jpg`
  });

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  };

  axios
    .post("https://prezzi-api.herokuapp.com/upload", formData, options)
    .then(response => {
      console.warn(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.warn("error uploading to OCR", error);
    });
};
```

My Express route looks like this:

```
router.post(
  "/",
  multer.single("image"),
  gcsMiddlewares.sendUploadToGCS,
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("post");
    if (req.file && req.file.gcsUrl) {
      return res.send(req.file.gcsUrl);
    }

    return res.status(500).send("Unable to upload");
  }
);
```

The console.log in my route does NOT get hit when I am not using Postman.

Answer (score 0):

1. write console.log({ uri }) inside your upload function to know in
   what format you are getting the uri
2. remove body from options

Comment: 1) console.log looks like: `Object {
  "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F4126F94-70FD-47A8-BC38-F2BD09215F0A/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540pivcec%252FPrezzi/Camera/03E523CD-748F-4808-8B7C-990CE2E003B6.jpg",
}`

2) body is removed from options

3) Server error persists

Answer (score 0):

I took a very close look at the `res` object in my Express route to see the differences between what works and what does not work, and here is what ended up working from React Native app:

```
      uploadToOCR = async uri => {
       const formData = new FormData();

       formData.append("image", {
         uri,
         name: "photo.jpg",
         type: "image/jpg",
         headers: {
           Accept: "application/json",
           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
         }
       });

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://prezzi-api.herokuapp.com/upload",
        options
      );
      if (response) {
        // const json = await response.json();
        // console.warn("json", json);
        console.warn("response", response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn("error uploading to OCR", error);
    }
 };
```